Conditional rendering of multiple tables in Vue.js
I'm building a Vue.js application that requires conditional rendering of multiple tables based on certain conditions. I have a set of flags that determine which tables should be rendered, and I'm struggling to find a clean and efficient way to implement this.
<Table1 v-if="flag1 && !flag2 && !flag3" />
<Table2 v-if="flag2 && !flag1 && !flag3" />
<Table3 v-if="flag3 && !flag1 && !flag2" />

As you can see, this approach is repetitive and error-prone. I'm looking for a way to simplify this code and make it more maintainable.
Using a single v-if statement with multiple conditions
Creating a separate component for each table
Using a mixin to handle the conditional rendering
What i want is
A clean and efficient way to conditionally render multiple tables based on a set of flags
A solution that is easy to maintain and extend
<template>
  <div>
    <Table1 v-if="flag1 && !flag2 && !flag3" />
    <Table2 v-if="flag2 && !flag1 && !flag3" />
    <Table3 v-if="flag3 && !flag1 && !flag2" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      flag1: true,
      flag2: false,
      flag3: false
    }
  }
}
</script>


Simply use: <Table1 v-if="flag1" /> <Table2 v-if="flag2" /> <Table3 v-if="flag3" /> you can also use v-if-else. check documentation: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional#v-else-if

you can accept an answer (the gray checkbox) btw, even better than upvoting

The problem that you don't render multiple tables, you render only one at a time. For that you need a state variable instead of multiple booleans (you can name your variable as you like):
<template>
  <div>
    <Table1 v-if="tableNum === 1" />
    <Table2 v-if="tableNum === 2" />
    <Table3 v-if="tableNum === 3" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tableNum: 1
    }
  }
}
</script>

Another option is to use component:
<template>
  <div>
    <Component :is="[Table1, Table2, Table3][tableNum -1]" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tableNum: 1
    }
  }
}
</script>


@Khan If your intent is to display one table at a time, this is the correct answer

I certainly advice to use a component-based method: it can be nicely adopted for any scenario.
